# Local development (invoking python <script>, port 8888) serves stale files

Tags: python, fastcgi, ubuntu-12.10

I had a similar issue when running fast-cgi and I was told there is no way to fix it: [Files being served are stale / cached ; Python as fcgi + web.py + nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679298/files-being-served-are-stale-cached-python-as-fcgi-web-py-nginx) without doing custom work. I was told to use the python  method, which invokes a local "web server" to host the python page.

Even doing that, the files served are stale / cached. If I make edits to the files, save and refresh, the python web server is still serving the stale / cached file.

The only way to get it to serve the modified file is to kill (ctrl+c) the script, and then restart...this takes about 5 seconds every-time and seriously impedes my development workflow.

Ideally any change to the script would be reflected next time the page is requested from the web server.

EDIT

@Jordan: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried #2, which yields the following error:

```
    app = web.application(urls, globals(), web.reloader)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reloader'
```

Per the documentation here: http://webpy.org/tutorial2.en

I then tried suggestion #4,

```
web.config.debug = True
```

Both still cause 'stale' files to get served.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code to reproduce this? (I have experienced this issue with pretty much any long-running python service I've built. There are several possible solutions, but they don't all fit with all python-based web frameworks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understandably you want a simple, set it up once and never worry about it again, solution.  But you might be making this problem more difficult than it needs to be.

I generally write applications for an apache/modwsgi/nginx stack.  If I have a caching problem, I just restart apache and voila, my python files are re-interpreted.  I don't remember the commands to restart apache on all of my different boxes (mac's, ubuntu, centos, etc), and I shouldn't need to.

*That is what command line aliases are for...*

A python application is interpreted *before* it is run, and when run on a webserver, it is run *once* and should be considered stateless.  This is unlike javascript running in a browser, which can be considered to have state since it is a continually running VM.  You can edit javascript while it is running and that is probably fine for most applications of the language.

In python you generally write the code, run it, and if that doesn't work you start over.  You don't edit the code in real time.  That means you are knowingly saving the source and changing contexts to run it.

I am betting that you are editing your source from a Graphical IDE instead of a command-line editor like vi or emacs (I might be wrong, and I'm not saying there is anything 'wrong' with that).  I only write iOS applications using an IDE, everything else I stick to [ViM](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/).  Why? Because then I am always on the command line, and I am not distracted by anything (animations, mouse pointers, notifications).  I finish writing my code, i quickly type ':wq' (write and quit), and then quickly type 'restartweb' (actually i usually type 're' then <\tab> to auto-complete) which is my **alias** to whatever the command to restart apache is.  Voila my python is reinterpreted.

My point is that you should probably keep it simple and use something like an **alias** to solve your problem.  It might not be the *coolest* thing you could do.  But it is what Ninja coders have been doing for the last 20 years to get work done fast and simple.

Now obviously I only suggested a solution for apache, and I have never used web.py before.  But the same possible solution still applies.  Make a bash script that goes in your project directory, call it something like *restart.bash*.  In it put something like:

```
rm -r *.pyc
```

Which will recursively remove all compiled pyc files, forcing your app to reload.  Then make an **alias** in your *~/.bashrc* that runs that file

Something like:

```
alias restartproject="bash /full/path/to/restart.bash"
```

Magical, now you have a solution that works everywhere, regardless of which type of web server you choose to run your application from.

**Edit:**
*Now you have a solution that works everywhere but on a Windows IIS server.  And if you are trying to run python from Windows, you should probably Stahp!  hugz*

We are using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/) right? :)  We want to keep our python nice and system-agnostic so we can sell it to anyone right?  :)  And you should really check out ViM and emacs if you don't use them... you will bang your head against the wall for a week getting used to it, then never want to touch a mouse again after that.

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv, in fact I just stumbled upon it yesterday when installing a web front end to mongo. Otherwise I hear what you're saying. I think it makes sense and I need to approach this a little differently. Thanks.

Comment: seriously, use virtualenv, you might not think you need it, but it always makes your life easier.  i.e. -> dev something on your ubuntu box, suddenly you decide to buy an OSX machine while in the middle of a project, you move your stuff to the new box and suddenly you are missing dependencies everywhere.  with virtualenv a couple calls to 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' and 'pip install requirements.txt' is a heck of alot easier than trying to manually install dependencies and dealing with errors

Comment: and then you just include the requirements.txt in your mercurial repository and even better now, your dependencies are included in your source control! :)

Comment: lol, and now that i said that, you should definitely be using source control if you aren't... :)  Some people will flame it, but you should probably check out mercurial if you don't use it.  mercurial is my girlfriend.  she treats me good.  unless i am working with a massive team there is very little reason to use git/cvs/tfs(you don't wanna know what this is)

Answer (score 1):

Right, so Python is a compiled language when run on a web server. It's outputting a .pyc file that's the compiled version. Your goal is to tell the web server that the .pyc file is out of date and is no longer valid.

You have a few options:

1. Delete the relevant .pyc file
2. For web.py, use the reloader middleware
3. Send it a HUP signal (I'm lazy and usually do killall -SIGHUP python). You can do this automatically with a file watching tool like watchdog (thanks barracel).
4. web.config.debug = True should be the default in your application

None of those options are working for you?

Comment: HUP works, but that's a crappy workflow. I just want to edit the file and refresh in the browser to the see changes. I'll checkout web.config.debug, hopefully that works. I'll report back tonight.

Comment: You can use [watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) to monitor file modifications and send HUP signal

Comment: Added @barracel's comment into the answer. Thanks.

Comment: For development I would recommend option #2, and running your app using web.run(). nginx/fcgi is a good production setup but it will lack such niceties as automatically reloading code and debugging helpers.

Comment: I've updated my original question w/the results of #2 and #4.

Comment: Some servers will automatically update whenever you edit a file. Cherrypy does this, and App Engine's dev server.

Comment: Just a nitpicky thing, but the statement, "Python is a compiled language", is never correct.  Python is an interpreted language.  Yes .pyc's are created by _compilation_, but it is compiled to python bytecode.  This bytecode is then interpreted, so it is still an interpreted language.  The bytecode can just be thought of as a compressed version of the verbose source you already wrote.

Comment: Unless you are talking about RPython, which can be compiled by the LLVM compiler... :)  But thats not _REALLY_ python

Comment: Compilation to bytecode is still compilation. The point is that it is in a form closer to machine language. It's not just compression of verbose source, it's also doing other optimizations. More details are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both